# How and how often to water ZZ plant leaf cuttings

Tags: houseplants, watering, cuttings

I have made 3 leaf cuttings of my ZZ plant and planted the leaves in pots on a window sill.

I am confused about the watering of the cuttings. I have read conflicting information and now I don't know if I should mist them, water them very frequently, or wait for roots to develop before watering them at all.

How and how often should I water my ZZ plant leaf cuttings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very creative way to ask a question, Gilles!  The most important thing is keeping moist but NOT SOGGY.  Shallow watering daily.  I'd use a bottle sprayer.  Until roots have grown do not water the entire pot of soil.  How large is the pot or container?  Hopefully it is no larger than 3X3 inches!  Too big of a container for starting anything will not work.  Too large of a container for a small plant will not work.  Need roots to suck up water or else root rot is a high possibility...as well as slow start and other potential problems.  Use ONLY potting soil.  Sterilized potting soil.  Drainage hole, I would not use tap water, bottled water without chlorine/fluoride is best and do not use fertilizer until you've got a decent root growth.  Covering with a dome or plastic is very helpful and will reduce the need to constantly check the soil for moisture.  What kind of light source?

Comment: Oh... The container is about 3-4 inches I guess. I have used potting soil but I don't know if it's sterilized. I have watered with tap water and haven't used a plastic dome. The light source is the light of an East facing window. I will correct these points next time I take cuttings.